# Callback not provided pattern in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express, callback

I usually write NodeJS code for hours, and there is a common situation I'm not sure how to face. Given the following async function call (where we forget the needed callback):

```
function foo (callback) {
    // Perform a task and call callback when finished
    callback();
}
foo(); // We forget the callback
```

Which is the better way to handle this? I find two options:

1. Make `foo()` function more robust adding this as the first line: `callback = callback || function () {}`.
2. Let it crash when `foo()` tries to call `callback()` and it does not exist.

Maybe a third option (which I prefer) would be the best one: throwing a custom error if the callback is not provided, as the first lines of `foo()`. For instance:

```
function foo (callback) {
    if (!callback) {
        throw new Error('No callback provided');
    }
    // More stuff here
    callback();
}
```

My question is:
Is there any well-known patten to solve this situation? Which approach do you think is the better one? Do you solve this in a different way?

Comment: Are you tried to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for async functions? It brings some new approaches for designing without callbacks.

Answer (score 4):

It all depends if your callback is mandatory or not.

- **If it is mandatory** then you should fail fast and do the `throw new Error('No callback provided');`.
- **If it is optional** then the standard practice is that you just call it if it exists. Instead of creating a new function, just add a check in the place where it is gonna get called:

  ```
  if ( callback ) {
     callback();
  }
  ```

or in a single line:

```
callback && callback();
```

Comment: Would `typeof callback === "function"` work better here?

Comment: @BenFortune if you have a variable called "callback", semantically places it as type function,  I rather call it and have the code fail if it is not a function. That way it is easier to know that something wrong is being stored in the callback.